# Getting HW transcoding to work on headless machine

Tags: xorg, display, directory, development, plex

Okay i give up..

Im done.. I cant for the life of me get HW transcoding to work on my plex server.. Im out of ideas.. Im pretty new to this Linux thing.. But i have read everything i could find and i cant get it to work.. Ive tried installing vaapi, reconfigure xorg. Installing that dummy monitor thing Nothing works! I even had hetzner turn on onboard graphics in the bios.. and still nothing.. The server is running a Intel Xeon E3-1275V6 So that should be good.. Im so tired right now so i will check back here tomorrow if anybody needs any information

But i never had a /dev/dri folder and when ever i do vainfo i just come up with and error that there is no display.. And as far as i can understand the reason that there is no /dev/dri folder is because the server dosent detect a monitor.. But atm i have no idea

Comment: I can't help but probably those that can will need to know what Linux Kernel version and Ubuntu version you are using.

Comment: what kind of gpu do you have? The output of `lspci | grep VGA` would be nice.